# upload image and attempt OCR from Drive Android API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, ocr

I'm trying to upload an image to google drive from android code and perform ocr on it.
Can't figure out how the ocr option should be requested. I read several answers here on SO saying there is a .insert() method somewhere that I should be using but I can't find such a method. The Android Developer site fails to provide proper documentation on this api.

If someone could just tell me what to add to my code please:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

...

    private class EditFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DriveApi.ContentsResult, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(DriveApi.ContentsResult... params) {
            DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult = params[0];
            if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Failed to create new contents.");
                return false;
            }
            showMessage("New contents created.");
            OutputStream outputStream = contentsResult.getContents().getOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmapToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
            try {
                outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage("Unable to write file contents.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                    .setTitle("rochale1.jpg")
                    .build();

            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialContents(contentsResult.getContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                showMessage("Failed to launch file chooser.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (!result) {
                showMessage("Error while editing contents");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming this task would be the place to request ocr, if not please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP script to upload the file using insert method which seems to be the task you are trying to accomplish for Android - not sure if this will help but this does explain the insert method below....

You can also edit the file properties after its loaded which might be a solution for you using "patch" method

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

```
function uploadFile($service,$title,$description,$filePath,$mtype){

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle($title.".pdf");
$file->setDescription($description);
$file->setMimeType('application/pdf');

$data = file_get_contents($filePath);

sleep(1);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mtype,
      'uploadType' => 'multipart',
      'convert' => true,
          'ocr'=> true
    ));


return ($createdFile);
```

}